# Manage HTTP Session from inside T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, rest, t-sql

I am using T-SQL to call to get data from an API.

Let me be the first to say: this is not ideal.
Code base cannot be altered and I'm left on the database side to "make it work" on our internal network (not public facing).

I am able to get a "Login successful" response back from the API using the script below.
Problem is, this API does not use Tokens for authentication. Therefore I cannot pass the token back in a second query as a header.

```
DECLARE @AUTH_URL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '_api_url_login_';

Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @Status as Int;

Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post', @AUTH_URL, 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', NULL, '{"username":"___", "password":"___"}'
Exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'status', @Status OUT
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
```

Logging in to the site and calling the API directly from Chrome and Postman work but not SQL Server. I think it's because SQL Server does not maintain HTTP session state.

GET request code is below, and I'm receiving a generic error from the API (unable to post the error).

Below is my code for the GET request:

```
DECLARE @JOB_URL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '_api_url_';

Declare @Object2 as Int;
Declare @Status2 as Int;

Declare @ResponseText2 as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object2 OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object2, 'open', NULL, 'get', @JOB_URL, 'False'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object2, 'send'
Exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object2, 'status', @Status2 OUT
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object2, 'responseText', @ResponseText2 OUTPUT

select @ResponseText2
select @Status2
```

Any help on sending both of these queries in a single HTTP session using T-SQL?

Comment: Maybe you can use SQL Server SSIS Script Task (c#) to make HTTP calls in your environment.

Comment: Don't have license for SSIS, and cannot get unfortunately...

Comment: There is no need in any additional license for SSIS. It is covered by the SQL Server instance license

Comment: Can you put it in a CLR procedure?

Comment: Talked to the lead engineer and SSIS and CLR procs are not allowed..

Comment: Lucky you... you might have to turn around and say this functionality isn't possible then if they want to totally hamstring you.

Comment: Hang on, if its not using token auth, then what is it using? You shouldn't need session state, at your end, that the server end.

Comment: Or maybe a Powershell script which you can put in a SQL Agent Job. Using `sp_OA` is a terribly bad idea.

Comment: Second the horrors of `sp_OA` procs. They do nothing for the reliability and stability of your SQL Server instance, especially when you're not doing any error checking or actually destroying the object when you're done (or failed).

Comment: So if you're not getting an OAuth token back in the auth response's body... are you getting `Set-Cookie` headers in the response headers? Are you meant to be including a `Cookie:` header in subsequent requests?

Comment: The server just returns “Login successful” and then a json text with the user details (username, email, password). I’ll have to confirm tomorrow but don’t remember anything usable coming back to Postman. Ultimately, think Powershell script via sproc is going to be the best bet…

Comment: Check the headers

Comment: An api that uses cookies for state sounds like someone misunderstood something badly. What happens if you reuse the original OA-object and use it for further requests?

Comment: Tried for hour and a half to get Powershell going correctly, but had issue with sending the body of post request (worked from Powershell, not from sql server). At any rate, @siggemannen suggestion worked

Comment: @Hyper10n you do have a license for SSIS - it's included free with SQl Server. And *every, **every*** other option is easier, faster and safer than this

Comment: `Tried for hour and a half to get Powershell going correctly,` tried what? `Invoke-WebRequest` does in a single line what all this code is trying to do, and actually works.

Comment: `Talked to the lead engineer and SSIS and CLR procs are not allowed..` but enabling COM Automation is? Did you tell them you want to use COM Automation? If they have no issue with this, they don't know a lot about SQL Server or security. Those calls were explicitly disabled because they can execute *anything* on a server. These were actually used to spread worms in the 2000s

Comment: @Hyper10n, great, another satisfied sp_oa-customer. But i agree with Panagiotis, while i love these procs, they are brittle at best.

Comment: @siggemannen I don't love them. `Nuke them from orbit` isn't even enough for such code. I actually had to cleanup after Slammer and similar worms. The fact they require an administrator to modify the server configuration to enable them is more than enough warning that these *shouldn't* be used

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @siggemannen for the suggestion to **reuse the original OA-object for further requests**. Please provide an answer and I will accept

Below is the code that works...

```
--Login
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @AUTH_URL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '_api_url_login_';

Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @Status as Int;

Declare @Header as Varchar(8000);
Declare @Cookie as Varchar(8000);
Declare @ResponseText as varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post', @AUTH_URL, 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', NULL, '{"username":"___", "password":"___"}'

--Grab Data
------------------------------------------
DECLARE @JOB_URL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '_api_url_';

Declare @Object2 as Int;
Declare @Status2 as Int;

Declare @ResponseText2 as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @JOB_URL, 'False'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'status', @Status2 OUT
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText2 OUTPUT

select @ResponseText2 response
select @Status2 "status"

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Don't write such code. This code is fundamentally broken and unfixable. It's using insecure obsolete technologies, depends on Internet Explorer libraries (so it won't work on Linux), requires *weakening* security by enabling disabled features and can easily lead to memory leaks - any error will leave the COM objects you created orphaned in memory. The same `sp_OAMethod` calls you use here were used in the 2000s to spread worms through SQL Server